# On downloading Android source, all I get are a bunch of empty folders

Tags: android, git, open-source

I have tried the steps in the [Android Source](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) page.

I can see the sync happening but the process completes without downloading any real source files, there are only empty folders with some their names ending with {.git}.

Is there something wrong here ?

**or**

Is there a step I do not know of that will pull the source files to there respective folders ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same repository is also on github: https://github.com/android,

**platform_frameworks_base** is the actual android framework...